# VB - BinaryWriter inserting junk characters

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to create an MP3 ID3v1 Tag editor in Visual Basic (2010)

I have no problem reading tags, however, I can't seem to update the tags correctly.

I use FileStream to open the file, and then I use BinaryWriter. I seek to right after the "TAG" header, which is 125 bytes from the end of file.

The first field is the Title field, which is 30 characters long.

So before writing the new tag, I would clear it by writing 30 spaces.

Then I seek back to the beginning, and try to write the new data. But it ends up overwriting data in the next field.

```
        Dim file As New System.IO.FileStream(songpath, IO.FileMode.Open)
    Dim bw As New System.IO.StreamWriter(file)

    file.Seek(-125, IO.SeekOrigin.End)
    bw.Write("                             ")
    file.Seek(-125, IO.SeekOrigin.End)
    bw.Write(data(0))
    bw.Close()
    file.Close()
```

Here is a screen cap of the result. I attempted to write "Test" in the title field, I write the data and then reopen the file and this is what I get.

[image: here is a screen cap of the program]

Comment: You mention "BinaryWriter" (which is the wrong thing to use) in the title and question, but show a StreamWriter (which is also a wrong thing to use) in the code. Using [FileStream.Write](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream.write?view=netframework-4.7.2) should get you the desired result.

Comment: There's no `BinaryWriter` in your code.

Comment: If you're going to write using a `StreamWriter` then you need to consider the encoding being used.  The same text can produce different binary data depending on the encoding.

Comment: 30 **characters** or 30 **bytes**? And is ID3v1/2 fixed in size or dynamic in size?

Comment: @Lasse Vågsæther Karlsen  ID3v1 has a fixed size (125 bytes + the "TAG" identifier (start of structure) = 128 bytes). ID3V2 has a *dynamic* structure, divided in Header (fixed) Extended header (variable, optional), Frames (variable length) + 2 other optional parts (padding and Footer). In ID3v1, you can store simply bytes. There's no interpretation of the content nor predefined standard to read it's content encoding. The editor decides the format (ASCII, usually. Or the local CodePage).

Comment: Have you considered to use an existing library for this. One of the versions of [taglib](https://github.com/timheuer/taglib-sharp-portable), for example. You can install it using your NuGet Package Manager. Unless you just need to edit the ID3V1 for yourself.

Comment: I don't want to use an existing library because I'm writing my own for my own practice and use.

I believe that the StreamWriter is a typo, in my code I'm using BinaryWriter.

Comment: Well, that is good thing. You can learn a lot just testing this. Also, the ID3V1 can be modified to store data differently. Some of these *modifications* are considered a standard. See [this one](http://id3.org/ID3v1) for example. There, you can also find the documentation for ID3V2.x. Here's the [Developer's Documents page](http://id3.org/Developer%20Information).

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using `file.Seek`, I would set the `.Position` property, like this:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim f = "C:\temp\sample.MP3"

        Dim newTitle = "This is a test."
        Dim dataLen = 30
        Dim titleData(dataLen - 1) As Byte
        Dim newTitleBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(newTitle)
        Array.Copy(newTitleBytes, titleData, Math.Min(dataLen, newTitleBytes.Length))

        Using str As New FileStream(f, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None)
            Dim titlePosition = str.Length - 125
            str.Position = titlePosition
            str.Write(titleData, 0, dataLen)
        End Using

    End Sub

End Module
```

The unused portion of the title should be bytes with a value of zero - when you create an array its values are set to zero* for you. Then you can fill the start of the title bytes with the bytes which represent the string in ASCII. I suspect you could get away with using ISO-8859-1 if you need accented characters, but don't rely on that.

The [`Using`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement) construction makes sure that the file is closed afterwards even if something goes wrong.

<sub>* If it's an array of a numeric type, like Byte or Integer and so on.</sub>

Comment: Thank you, I will experiment with this as soon as I can and I'll let you know how it works.

Looks like I should learn more about Encoding and read up more on basic File I/O. I think I may have gotten ahead of myself with this.

Comment: [`.Position` uses `.Seek()` internally](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/filestream.cs,1221). Just a detail. The code is working.

Comment: I don't quite understand copying newTitleBytes into titleData. Why could I not just Write newTitleBytes? Is this the piece of code that fills up all 30 bytes if the string is shorter than 30 bytes?

Otherwise that's excellent and it works fine now.

Comment: @scytheblade69 Yes, all 30 bytes need to be written to make sure the previous data is over-written. If you're happy with this answer, please mark it as "accepted" - there should be a tick mark next to the up/down vote buttons. ([Help page: What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers))